# Image not loading in the imageview from the url

Tags: android, url, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

I am trying to set a bitmap to imageview using url in the following way : -

```
     InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();

     image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); 

     in.close();
```

When i get the image from the tomcat server using url like : -

```
http://192.168.1.6:8080/webapp/images/image.jpg
```

This works totally .

The problem is , when i set the url of image from any other website say - http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ipk1-aQaWyw/maxresdefault.jpg

then no image is being set on the imageview.

I tried using the ip address instead of the domain name , but still no luck.

Do i need to set any port number too ? like in the case of loading image from server ?

If yes , what port number should i use ?

Comment: Did you use AsyncTask for this?

Comment: yea, doing in the AsyncTask only

Comment: Try using other online links. And see if that works.

Comment: And yes, NO port number required for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this two things:

- Check if your device is on the same net than your server because it seems to be a local IP
- Have you tried to execute your code on the main thread. In Android, all changes have to be executed in the main thread, even if you are getting a web image (executing an asynk taksk). You can try this:

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

  ```
           @Override
           public void run() {
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); 
                      }

           });
  ```

Good luck with this!!